# React-Bootstrap table not showing using BootstrapTable library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm having an issue where the table isn't showing in my react application, after a few modification on adding the `Search` function it seems that the `BootstrapTable` itself disappear when saving it.

**ActionItems.jsx**

```js
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import ToolkitProvider, { Search } from "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit";
import paginationFactory from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';

export class ActionItems extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {  
            rowCount: 0
        };
    }

      render() {

        var pendingActionData = [
            {
                head1: 'Col1',
                action: 'Sample Action Required',
                type: 'type1'
            },
            {
                head1: 'Col2',
                action: 'Sample Action Required',
                type: 'type2'
            },
            {
                head1: 'Col5',
                action: 'Sample Action Required',
                type: 'type3'
            },
            {
                head1: 'Col6',
                action: 'Sample Action Required',
                type: 'type2'
            },
            {
                head1: 'Col7',
                action: 'Sample Action Required',
                type: 'type2'
            },
            {
                head1: 'Col8',
                action: 'Sample Action Required',
                type: 'type2'
            },
            {
                head1: 'Col9',
                action: 'Sample Action Required',
                type: 'type3'
            },
            {
                head1: 'Col10',
                action: 'Sample Action Required',
                type: 'type3'
            },
            {
                head1: 'Col3',
                action: 'Sample Action Required',
                type: 'type3'
            },
            {
                head1: 'Col4',
                action: 'Sample Action Required',
                type: 'type2'
            },
            {
                head1: 'Col11',
                action: 'Sample Action Required',
                type: 'type2'
            },
            {
                head1: 'Col12',
                action: 'Sample Action Required',
                type: 'type3'
            },
            {
                head1: 'Col13',
                action: 'Sample Action Required',
                type: 'type3'
            },
            {
                head1: 'Col14',
                action: 'Sample Action Required',
                type: 'type3'
            },
            {
                head1: 'Col15',
                action: 'Sample Action Required',
                type: 'type2'
            },
            {
                head1: 'Col16',
                action: 'Sample Action Required',
                type: 'type2'
            }
        ];

        var columns = [
            {  
                dataField: 'head1',  
                text: 'head1',
                sort: true
            },  
            {  
                dataField: 'action',  
                text: 'action',  
                sort:true  
            },
            {  
                dataField: 'type',  
                text: 'Type',  
                sort: true  
            }
        ];

        const defaultSortedList = [
            {
                dataField: 'head1',
                order: 'desc'
            }
        ];

        const pagination = paginationFactory({
            page: 1,
            sizePerPage: 10,
            lastPageText: '>>',
            firstPageText: '<<',
            nextPageText: '>',
            prePageText: '<',
            showTotal: true,
            alwaysShowAllBtns: true
          });

          const { SearchBar } = Search;
          
          
          return (
            <ToolkitProvider keyField="head1" data={pendingActionData} columns={columns} search>
                {
                    props => {
                        <div>
                            <SearchBar {...props.searchProps} />
                            <BootstrapTable {...props.baseProps} pagination={pagination} defaultSorted={defaultSortedList} striped hover />
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            </ToolkitProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default ActionItems;
```

**ActionListings.jsx**

```js
<Container>
    <Tabs>
        <Tab><ActionItems /></Tab
    </Tabs>
</Container>
```

I not certainly sure why this happens but I think I made some mistakes when I am trying to implement `Search` into it.  I follow this [guide](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/basic-search.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
props => {
    <div>
        <SearchBar {...props.searchProps} />
        <BootstrapTable {...props.baseProps} pagination={pagination} defaultSorted={defaultSortedList} striped hover />
     </div>
}
```

to

```
props => (
    <div>
        <SearchBar {...props.searchProps} />
        <BootstrapTable {...props.baseProps} pagination={pagination} defaultSorted={defaultSortedList} striped hover />
     </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it I missed up somewhere, didn't know that was so simple :)